# Django get raw query result as objects

Tags: mysql, sql, django, tuples

I recently started learn Django. I've 2 case. 1 of them works as I wanted. Other one is not.

Working case:

```
cursor = connections['ticket'].cursor()
        raw_query = "SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE customer_code = '%s'" % customer.custid
        cursor.execute(raw_query)
        tickets = cursor.fetchall()
```

And when I use tickets in template:

```
{{ ticket.name }}
```

It prints its value.

Now other not working case:

```
cursor = connections['ubds'].cursor()
        raw_query = """SELECT  * FROM IncomeTransactions WHERE CustID = '%s' AND TranType = '17'"""\
                    """ORDER BY TranDate ASC""" % (request.session['member_id'])
        cursor.execute(raw_query)
        invoices = cursor.fetchall()
```

And when I print its value in print:

```
{{ invoice.name }} #blank result
```

Its not printing anything. Just blank. But when I access into index and print it works

```
{{ invoice.2 }} #it printing 3rd column from table
```

I suspect first one return object, but second one returning array (tuple). But they both used same functions. What could be reason? How can I access via column name on 2nd case?

Edit: Print result on both cases

```
print tickets
```

[(917235, 162, None, datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=), u'0001-08', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'0002', None, None, 8199484.0, u'\u0414\u0443\u043b\u0430\u0430\u043d\u044b \u04af\u043d\u044d ', 17, None, None, None, None, u'192.168.0.101', u'mijiddorj', 29522, 19, 3, None, None, None), (920746, 681, None, datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=), u'0001-08', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'0002', None, None, 5237942.0, u'\u0414\u0443\u043b\u0430\u0430\u043d\u044b \u04af\u043d\u044d ', 17, None, None, None, None, u'192.168.0.141', u'mijiddorj', 29522, 19, 3, None, None, None), (924625, 1148, None, datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=), u'0001-08', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'0002', None, None, 6574669.0, u'\u0414\u0443\u043b\u0430\u0430\u043d\u044b \u04af\u043d\u044d ', 17, None, None, None, None, u'192.168.0.141', u'mijiddorj', 29522, 19, 3, None, None, None), (928477, 1690, None, datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=), u'0001-08', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'0002', None, None, 4269964.0, u'\u0414\u0443\u043b\u0430\u0430\u043d\u044b \u04af\u043d\u044d ', 17, None, None, None, None, u'192.168.0.31', u'mijiddorj', 29522, 19, 3, None, None, None), (932106, 1103, None, datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 19, 0, 0, tzinfo=), u'0001-04', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'0002', None, None, 2408917.0, u'\u0414\u0443\u043b\u0430\u0430\u043d\u044b \u04af\u043d\u044d ', 17, None, None, None, None, u'192.168.0.121', u'mijiddorj', 29522, 19, 3, None, None, None), (934461, 173, None, datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 20, 0, 0, tzinfo=), u'0001-08', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'0002', None, None, 12024.0, u'\u0414\u0443\u043b\u0430\u0430\u043d\u044b \u04af\u043d\u044d ', 17, None, None, None, None, u'192.168.0.109', u'mijiddorj', 29522, 19, 3, None, None, None), (936002, 8, None, datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=), u'0001-04', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'0002', None, None, 52355.0, u'\u0414\u0443\u043b\u0430\u0430\u043d\u044b \u04af\u043d\u044d ', 17, None, None, None, None, u'192.168.0.75', u'mijiddorj', 29522, 19, 3, None, None, None), (938032, 16, None, datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 20, 0, 0, tzinfo=), u'0001-08', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'0002', None, None, 40833.0, u'\u0414\u0443\u043b\u0430\u0430\u043d\u044b \u04af\u043d\u044d ', 17, None, None, None, None, u'192.168.0.78', u'mijiddorj', 29522, 19, 3, None, None, None), (940140, 53, None, datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 0, 0, tzinfo=), u'0001-08', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'0002', None, None, 1399746.0, u'\u0414\u0443\u043b\u0430\u0430\u043d\u044b \u04af\u043d\u044d ', 17, None, None, None, None, u'192.168.0.143', u'mijiddorj', 29522, 19, 3, None, None, None), (942116, 179, None, datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=), u'0001-08', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'0002', None, None, 40833.0, u'\u0414\u0443\u043b\u0430\u0430\u043d\u044b \u04af\u043d\u044d ', 17, None, None, None, None, u'192.168.0.54', u'mijiddorj', 29522, 19, 3, None, None, None), (946440, 96, None, datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=), u'0001-08', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'0002', None, None, 270453.0, u'\u0414\u0443\u043b\u0430\u0430\u043d\u044b \u04af\u043d\u044d ', 17, None, None, None, None, u'192.168.0.196', u'mijiddorj', 29522, 19, 3, None, None, None), (949055, 105, None, datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 13, 0, 0, tzinfo=), u'0001-08', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'0002', None, None, 2869320.0, u'\u0414\u0443\u043b\u0430\u0430\u043d\u044b \u04af\u043d\u044d ', 17, None, None, None, None, u'192.168.0.196', u'mijiddorj', 29522, 19, 3, None, None, None), (952901, 169, None, datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=), u'0001-08', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'0002', None, None, 7107883.0, u'\u0414\u0443\u043b\u0430\u0430\u043d\u044b \u04af\u043d\u044d ', 17, None, None, None, None, u'192.168.0.196', u'mijiddorj', 29522, 19, 3, None, None, None), (1118349, 177, None, datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 19, 0, 0, tzinfo=), u'0001-08', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'0002', None, None, 7546811.0, u'\u0414\u0443\u043b\u0430\u0430\u043d\u044b \u04af\u043d\u044d ', 17, None, None, None, None, u'192.168.0.63', u'Handaa', 29522, 19, 3, None, None, None), (1122726, 273, None, datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=), u'0001-08', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'0002', None, None, 8005173.0, u'\u0414\u0443\u043b\u0430\u0430\u043d\u044b \u04af\u043d\u044d ', 17, None, None, None, None, u'192.168.0.75', u'Handaa', 29522, 19, 3, None, None, None)]

```
print invoices
```

((1L, u'T15021715135295', 2L, u'call', u'\u0428\u0443\u0443\u0434 \u0445\u0430\u0440\u0438\u0443\u043b\u0441\u0430\u043d. test122123', u'closed', u'99881122', 2L, u'\u0414\u04af\u0433\u044d\u0440\u0445\u04af\u04af \u042d\u043d\u0445\u0447\u0438\u043c\u044d\u0433', 4L, u'\u0414\u0430\u0432\u0430\u0430\u0445\u04af\u04af  \u0410\u043b\u0442\u0430\u043d\u043d\u0430\u0432\u0447', 10L, u'\u0410\u0432\u0442\u043e \u0430\u0436 \u0430\u0445\u0443\u0439\u043d \u0430\u043b\u0431\u0430', datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 21, 15, 13, 52, tzinfo=), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 26, 18, 53, 36, tzinfo=), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 26, 17, 20, tzinfo=), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 17, 15, 13, 52, tzinfo=), None, None, None, u'agent-101-1424234875-330.wav', u'0002', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'', None, u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', '\x01', '\x00', '\x01', '\x01'), (2L, u'T15030212560836', 2L, u'call', u'test test', u'open', u'99081133', 2L, u'\u0414\u04af\u0433\u044d\u0440\u0445\u04af\u04af \u042d\u043d\u0445\u0447\u0438\u043c\u044d\u0433', None, None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 2, 12, 56, 8, tzinfo=), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 2, 12, 56, 8, tzinfo=), None, None, u'', None, None, None, u'0002', u'\u0410\u0437\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0438\u0441 \u0425\u0425\u041a', u'\u0411\u043e\u043b\u0434', 14000L, u'3', u'\u0410\u043c\u0430\u0440', u'55', u'55', u'boldoo@gmail.com', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00'))

Difference is 1st one (working one) have [( )], but 2nd one (not working one) have (( )).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, I don't understand why the first example works.  It shouldn't - `cursor.fetchall()` always returns list of tuples.

But if you want to get the list of dicts instead of tuples then use the recipe from the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly):

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    desc = cursor.description
    return [dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
              for row in cursor.fetchall()]
...
cursor.execute(raw_query)
invoices = dictfetchall(cursor)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure on 1st case. I using {{ invoice.Amount }} in template and its printing results

Comment: Look at the content of the `tockets` and `invoices` lists from your question.  They contain a tuples so `{{ invoice.Amount }}` couldn't work.  Seem like you getting the `{{ invoice }}` variable from some other source, not from these lists.

Comment: Sorry for long time. I just arrived at my work and tested. Works perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch raw results as model instances, use the `raw()` queryset method:

```
raw_query = "SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE customer_code = '%s'"
tickets = Ticket.objects.raw(raw_query, params=[customer.custid])
```

**Always** (yes, always) pass your parameters with the `params` parameter, this will protect you against SQL injection attacks. You should do the same when passing parameters to `cursor.execute`.

Comment: Do I have to create Ticket object and import it?

Comment: If you want to use the ORM, yes... you'll have to create a `Ticket` [model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/) and import it.